# Parsley.js : how to make a custom validator of out an existing one

Tags: javascript, validation, parsley.js

I'd like to validate a form field with a custom validator. I want the validation rule to accept:

- a URL,
- a [magnet URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme),
- a [ed2k URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed2k_URI_scheme).

I think I can easily find the regex for magnet and ed2k, but I'd like to use Parsley's url validation in my custom validator. How can I use it (I mean without duplicating the regex from Parsley's code)?

Answer (score 1):

You can call a builtin validator in this fashion:

```
var urlInput = $('<input>').parsley({type: 'url'});

window.Parsley.addValidator('ownUrlValidator', {
  validateString: function (value, requirements) {
    return urlInput.isValid({value: value}) || // rest of your validator...
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your own regex validation inside the `validateString` function of Parsley Custom Validator.

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('ownUrlValidator', {
  validateString: function (value, requirements) {
    console.log("validating", value, requirements);

    //Validate your URL with the regex here
     var regExp = /^(https?|s?ftp|git):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i;

    return '' !== value ? regExp.test( value ) : false;

  },
  messages: {
    en: 'Invalid URL'
  }
});
```